# Complex Joins SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, join, left-join, outer-join

I have a business problem which is to find the best price for a product for sale with the caveat that the best price when a bid should be the maximum for the seller.

There are three tables as follows - catalogue table (all parts which could be sold), retailer table for parts (the parts sold by retailers which are catalogued to be valid), retailer table for parts for which they have bid a price (parts not normally sold but the retailer can sell them).

Hence the conditions are:
1. A part must be catalogued to be sold.
2. Prices from the retailer part table will be presented to the user in price order (lowest first).
3. If the retailer does not normally sell a part but can sell it, he can bid a price which is the lowest he can sell at, but we want to present the highest price to the user for the bid but is less than the minimum price normally sold via retail.

Example:
Product = P, 3 Retailers sell P at prices RP1..3, 1 Retailer does not sell P but can sell P and he bids BP1 as the minimum price.

If Rp1..3 = 10,34, 56 and BP1 = 5, the selling price is 9.99 (10-0.01) by Bid retailer 1.

If BP1 = null, the selling price is 10 (by R1)
If BP1 = 12, the selling price is 10 (by R1)

If several retailers bid on the price then the one who has the lowest min price is selected but the same price-0.01 is used to compute the actual price.

I have been working with the catalogue table and the retailer table and that all works but the bid table has caused me some issues. To avoid programming changes I want to keep the changes in the sql only and then the system can remain the same.

I have my attempt below which does not work but I think it is basically correct aside from syntax errors and the 0.01 calculation is not included or the selection when we have multiple bidders.

```
select trp.ManPartNumber, r.retailername,r.retailerid,  
trp.retailerparturl, trp.partprice  from trahanretailerpart trp inner
join trahanpart tp  on trp.manpartnumber = tp.manpartnumber  and 
trp.manpartnumber = 'PM BAS C' and trp.currentpart = 1  and 
trp.currencyid = 1 inner join trahanretailer r on trp.retailerid = 
r.retailerid  inner join trahanshop s on s.shopid= trp.shopid  and  
s.shopname = 'Bristan'   as retailerparts outer join on  ( select 
trp.ManPartNumber, r.retailername, r.retailerid, 'soogr.com' as 
retailerparturl, trp.minpartprice as partprice  from trahanbestprice
trp inner join trahanpart tp  on trp.manpartnumber = tp.manpartnumber 
and trp.manpartnumber = 'PM BAS C' and trp.liveprice = 1  and 
trp.currencyid = 1 inner join trahanretailer r on trp.retailerid = 
r.retailerid  inner join trahanshop s on s.shopid= trp.shopid  and 
s.shopname = 'Bristan') as minpriceparts on minpriceparts.partprice < 
retailerparts.partprice  and retailerparts.retailerid != 
minpriceparts.retailerid  order by minpriceparts.partprice asc, 
retailerparts.partprice asc
```

Hence trahanpart is the catalogue table, trahanretailerpart is the retailer table, trahanbestprice is the bid table. Trahanshop, trahanretailer are used for brand and retailer names only. The partnumber may be duplicated across brands (aka shops in the design for historical reasons), trahanshop should be called trahanbrand.

Has anyone any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by using a UNION and then some processing logic in the code to remove the duplicate rows. It all works and I tested it.